# Are dangerous rays emitted during Solar Eclipse?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, sun, vision, eclipse, laboratory-safety

It is said one should avoid staring at Sun as it can damage the eyes, but it is also said that one should not come out in sun during eclipse as it emits dangerous rays. Is that true? If yes, why?

Comment: How could Moon possibly affect the Sun to make it emit dangerous rays? I bet the danger comes solely from the contrast.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's certainly no problem being out in the Sun during an eclipse: There's nothing being emitted then that's not being emitted at other times. The danger is just that the relative darkness near totality may make it seem safe to look at the Sun, even when it's not. But as long as you don't look directly at the Sun, you're fine.

During the time when an eclipse is total, it is safe to look at it with the naked eye. But ***only*** during totality. Even when the eclipse is almost total -- a thin crescent or even just [Bailey's beads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baily%27s_beads) or the [diamond ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_ring_effect) visible -- you can damage your eyes by looking at it. So if you're planning to view an eclipse, be sure you can identify totality before looking with the naked eye. Viewing with an experienced eclipse-watcher is a good idea if you can arrange it.

As [Mr. Eclipse](http://www.mreclipse.com/Totality/TotalityCh11.html) puts it

> Permanent eye damage can result from
>   looking at the disk of the Sun
>   directly, or through a camera
>   viewfinder, or with binoculars or a
>   telescope even when only a thin
>   crescent of the Sun or Baily's Beads
>   remain. The 1 percent of the Sun's
>   surface still visible is about 10,000
>   times brighter than the full moon.
>   Staring at the Sun under such
>   circumstances is like using a
>   magnifying glass to focus sunlight
>   onto tinder. The retina is delicate
>   and irreplaceable. There is little or
>   nothing a retinal surgeon will be able
>   to do to help you. Never look at the
>   Sun outside of the total phase of an
>   eclipse unless you have adequate eye
>   protection.

Answer (score 5):

It's amazing how long the solar eclipse myth persists in spite of attempts to educate the public. There are still school principals in many countries that deny children the opportunity to view totality, one of the most wonderful sights in nature. During partial eclipse phases, solar filters that reduce luminosity by a factor of 10^5 will permit safe viewing. However, during totality, no filtering is required since the luminosity approximates that of a full moon. In my eclipse trips we often passed out filters to the interested public.

Comment: Yeah, but that only applies if you're at a place that falls totally under the umbra, otherwise there won't be any safe moment to look up unprotected; so knowing how children can tend to ignore "small details" I'd say it's better to be safe than sorry?